# Couldn't retrieve data: GET request to localhost server

Tags: java, database, rest

This is the message I get in the console for my website:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/users?pageNumber=1&pageSize=5 400 (Bad Request)
```

I also receive a problem on my website:

```
problem retrieving data
```

I'm trying to build paging for my website and I'm still in the middle of doing this and I checked all my steps but I couldn't find the problem. Thank you for your help.

```java
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(int id, UserForUpdateDto userForUpdateDto)
{
    if (id != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
        return Unauthorized();

    var userFromRepo = await _repo.GetUser(id);

    _mapper.Map(userForUpdateDto, userFromRepo);

    if (await _repo.SaveAll())
        return NoContent();

    throw new Exception($"Updating user {id} failed on save");
}
```

Comment: I removed the [paging] tag because this isn't about operating-system development (paging is a memory-management technique). What server software do you use? You should use this as tag. Remember, the TAGS attract the right audience to your question, so if you use irrelevant tags you get the wrong audience and the audience you want don't see that question.